# Spark TextArea's visible text (paragraphs from text Flow)

Tags: apache-flex, position, textarea, paragraph

how can I find what char's are currently visible in sparks text area. I need to know position of first (and last) visible character. OR, even better, witch paragraphs (ParagraphElement's, from TextFlow) are visible (also start and end index).

Thanks.

Comment: some basic workaround to start.//spark TextArea ID: - textArea//
var str:String = textArea.text;
var tempStr:String = StringUtil.trim(str);
var firstChar:String = tempStr.substr(0,1);
var ind:int = str.indexOf(firstChar);
//First char index is stored in ind.
    
var nLines:* = textArea.mx_internal::getTextFlow().flowComposer.numLines;
//you can get line number in text area.

Comment: number of lines can be found just using textArea.textFlow.mxmlChildren.length()

Comment: Please read below link you will get some idea and after doing some work around you can achieve what you are looking for: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705762/how-can-i-read-a-spark-textarea-implicit-line-breaks

Comment: I couldn't find anything that would help me. I know how to find length of every line. I need to know what lines are visible. For an instance, if I have 5000 lines of code, and user scrolls down to see some part of code, i need to know which lines are shown( rendered ). In any case, thanks for replaying.