# How can I read a spark TextArea implicit line breaks?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I have a TextArea where the user can enter text and also change the width and height of the TextArea. When resizing, the text is breaking where expected. I need to find where the TextArea skin added the implicit line breaks after resizing.

**ENVIRONMENT**

- FlexBuilder 4.6
- Flex SDK 4.6.0
- Flash Player 11.1

**EXAMPLE**

```
This is just plain text that
breaks after the word "that".
```

Any ideas on how to find the position of the line break when the TextArea lineBreak property is toFit and the text has no CR or LF characters? In the example above, it would be position 28.

Comment: Share your code? How is the user changing the height and width of the textarea?  I didn't think that was supported "out of box".  Are you sure there are no CF/LF Characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split up the text into line components and return their individual text lengths pretty easily, but you'll have to use some 'text layout framework' magic.

- First access your TextArea's `textFlow` property (not the `text` property), which will return a [TextFlow](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flashx/textLayout/elements/TextFlow.html) instance. This is a model for the text inside your TextArea.
- This object has a `flowComposer` which takes care of the layout of the text and carries a lot of information with it.
- Its type is [IFlowComposer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flashx/textLayout/compose/IFlowComposer.html), but you'll have to cast it to a [StandardFlowComposer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flashx/textLayout/compose/StandardFlowComposer.html) in order to access the individual lines.
- Now you have access to the `lines` property, which is a collection of [TextFlowLine](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flashx/textLayout/compose/TextFlowLine.html)
- Each of these lines has a `textLength` property.

So the following

```
var composer:StandardFlowComposer = 
    myTextArea.textFlow.flowComposer as StandardFlowComposer;
for each (var line:TextFlowLine in composer.lines) 
    trace(line.textLength)
```

would yield (with your example)

```
29
30
```

Comment: RIAstar, this worked perfectly. Thank you for the detailed explanation and example. My solution has a second text box who's lineBreak was set to explicit and the text was copied from the original textbox and explicit line breaks were inserted into the text string.